# How to redirect to a router with params in vue-routers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I want to organize my Vue Router like this:

| Original URL | Redirect to |
| --- | --- |
| `exmple.com/` | `exmple.com/en/home` |
| `exmple.com/:lang` | `exmple.com/:lang/home` (`:lang` is a param meaning language) |
| `example.com/:lang/home` | home page of `:lang` |
| `example.com/:lang/result/:date` | result page of a date |
| `example.com/:lang/result` | `exmaple.com/:lang/result/current_date` (`current_date` can be regarded as `new Date()`) |

Below is my vue-router config

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [{
        path: '/',
        redirect: '/en/home',
    },{
        path: '/:lang',
        name: 'lang',
        component: () => import("./Frame.vue"),
        redirect: {name: 'home'},
        children: [{
            path: 'home',
            name: 'home',
            component: () => import("./components/Home.vue")
        },{
            path: 'result/:date',
            name: 'result',
            component: () => import("./components/ResultDay.vue")
        },{
            path: 'result',
            redirect: {name: 'result', params: {date: new Date()}},
        }]
    }]
});
```

But it cannot redirect from `example.com/en/result` to `example.com/en/result/current_date`. JS console  shows an error as

> [vue-router] missing param for named route "result": Expected "lang" to be defined

So how can I pass the param `lang` to the "result" router?

Comment: If you want to implement i18n-enabled website, you may try this: https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/

Answer (score 0):

```
mode: 'history',
    routes: [{
        path: '/',
       //  redirect: '/en/home',
       // set default to lang base url 
        redirect: () => {
            return '/en'
        }
    },{
        path: '/:lang',
        name: 'lang',
        // component: () => import("./Frame.vue"),
        component: {
            template: '',  // if you have no special codes in Frame.vue
        },
        // redirect: {name: 'home'},
        redirect: to => ({
            path: '/'+to.params.lang+'/home',  // user lang passed by :lang
        }),
        children: [{
            path: 'home',
            name: 'home',
            component: () => import("./components/Home.vue")
        },{
            path: 'result/:date',
            name: 'result',
            component: () => import("./components/ResultDay.vue")
        },{
            path: 'result',
            redirect: {name: 'result', params: {date: new Date()}},
        }]
    }]
```